# Keep the Cache while Mount a new Snapshot of Azure CloudDrive

Tags: azure

The local cache for Azure CloudDrive is great for performance.

I recreate a new snapshot every 20 minutes, with little change or maybe no change at all in each snapshot.

To use the new snapshot, what I done is:

```
cloudDrive.Unmount();
cloudDrive = storageAccount.CreateCloudDrive(newSnapshotUri);
cloudDrive.Mount(size, option);
```

I like to know, will the old cache still be use for the new mount snapshot? Or the whole cache has to be rebuild again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is purely an educated guess, but I assume the cache is rebuilt. My reasoning is that you can't know when you mount the new snapshot what data is the same and what's different, so it would be impossible to figure out what to invalidate in the cache.

Comment: What I guess is guess to a good way, since all works on page, so at least the cacher should know each page changed or not maybe by a CSC32 or MD5 something, otherwise why role restart and it can still use the cache if `cleanOnRoleRecycle="false"`, anyway, I do not know the answer and do not know how to know the answer since the cache is a big one file. I know you are an insider, could you please ask someone who knows? Because if cache will lose, then I will choose NOT to change snapshot too often. And, is there a way to `.Swap()` snapshot not unmount and mount. Thanks

Comment: @EricYin Is it true that you can reuse the cache after a role instance restarts? I wouldn't have expected that either.

Comment: @EricYin I'll send this thread to someone on the storage team and see if I can get a comment from them.

Comment: check ms document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.clouddrive.initializecache.aspx Note that when you define the local storage resource for the cache, you should set the CleanOnRoleRecycle attribute to false, so that the cache data persists when the role is recycled.

Comment: btw, I believe the cache will not be reused for snapshot, because the cache filename changed, to something like `disk.vhd_2012_08_18T06_00_28.1016060Z.xdc`